# OpenCV capture black screen video

Tags: python, opencv

I'm doing video tests from an Aver Media GL310 capture device to a ps4, but when I show it in Python, only a black screen appears.

I'm using OpenCV and with the webcam everything works fine. Also, at first it didn't recognize the USB index until I installed the Aver Media software, but now it shows up as black. From the software the image appears fine.

I'm using some simple code, and after searching I tried to change resolution, fps, add python exceptions in antivirus, timeouts, but nothing seems to work.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("input", img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is an image, at low resolution it seems to be trying to show something, but at high resolution it is totally black.
I appreciate any response.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtCUv.png

Comment: check with vlc/ffshow/whatever to see if those programs can get a video feed that isn't black. -- use named constants like CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, **not** magic numbers like `3` and `4`. you're apparently following bad advice. distrust everything the author said. also because your code has no error checking at all on the usage of VideoCapture. follow official documentation and examples from OpenCV, not from random "famous" newbies on youtube or wherever. they will show you flashy stuff but no substance.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Understood, and use the aver media software to see the video if it was black, but there it is displayed normal. The problem is when displaying it in python.

Comment: don't just use their own tool. of course that'll work. use regular applications to check. -- -- details on the operating system would be useful. -- related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-capture-black-screen-video/7197

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
import cv2

#input your device number here.  For me it was 2.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("input", img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27: #ESC Key to exit
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I believe by default cv2 uses 640 x 480 (at least, for me it does if I don't specify).  So, if 640 x 480 is what you need, the above code should work.

Strangely though, if I try adding calls to cap.set(), then, like you, I experience some issues sometimes.  One of the following issues would occur: *

1. Issue 1. Fails to work; returns a black frame each time (and rather
   slowly at that... ~1 per second)
2. Issue 2. Mostly works; returns a black (or mostly black) frame as
   it's first frame, then returns frames normally.
   Note: Adding a call to time.sleep(.5) after the cap.set() calls, seems to eliminate issue 2, but does not help stop issue 1 from occurring.

   Note: Adding a call to time.sleep(.5) after the cap.set() calls, seems to eliminate issue 2, but does not help stop issue 1 from occurring.  Not sure what the best solution to issue 1 would be.  I tried putting everything in a method start_webcam() with a return False if the 3rd frame is black, then calling that method repeatedly until it works.  Like this:

> ```
> working = start_webcam()
>
> if working == False:
>     while(not working):
>         working = start_webcam()
> ```

This runs, exits and reruns start_webcam() until it's successful.  Surely there must be a cleaner way.

However, if, I use my other webcam (device 1), then it has no issue with calls to cap.set() and seems to run with no issues.... so likely something to do with the camera.

*Hopefully someone more experienced can elaborate what might be going on with cap.set() and how to avoid such issues.